Divergence between xml tag and code in libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor plugin
I am using ROS2 huble. I have a urdf with a link depicting an IMU. I am trying to simulate it in gazebo, and for that I have the following:
 <gazebo reference="${name}_link">
      <gravity>true</gravity>
      <sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
        <always_on>true</always_on>
        <update_rate>100</update_rate>
        <visualize>true</visualize>
        <topic>__default_topic__</topic>
        <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so" name="imu_plugin">
          <ros>
            <!-- publish to /gazebo_sim/imu/data -->
            <namespace>/gazebo_sim</namespace>
            <remapping>~/out:=imu/data</remapping>
          </ros>
          <frameName>${name}_link</frameName>
          <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
          <updateRateHz>10.0</updateRateHz>
          <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
          <xyzOffset>0 0 0</xyzOffset>
          <rpyOffset>0 0 0</rpyOffset>
          <initialOrientationAsReference>false</initialOrientationAsReference>
        </plugin>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      </sensor>
    </gazebo>

This, however is outputing a base_link on the topic header, and I get a warning about initial_orientation_as_reference not being set.
If I modify the tags so they are snake_case:
 <gazebo reference="${name}_link">
      <gravity>true</gravity>
      <sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
        <always_on>true</always_on>
        <update_rate>100</update_rate>
        <visualize>true</visualize>
        <topic>__default_topic__</topic>
        <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so" name="imu_plugin">
          <ros>
            <!-- publish to /gazebo_sim/imu/data -->
            <namespace>/gazebo_sim</namespace>
            <remapping>~/out:=imu/data</remapping>
          </ros>
          <frame_name>${name}_link</frame_name>
          <body_name>imu_link</body_name>
          <update_rate_HZ>10.0</update_rate_HZ>
          <gaussian_noise>0.0</gaussian_noise>
          <xyzOffset>0 0 0</xyzOffset>
          <rpyOffset>0 0 0</rpyOffset>
          <initial_orientation_as_reference>false</initial_orientation_as_reference>
        </plugin>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      </sensor>
    </gazebo>

The frame in the header is correct and I do not get the warning. This leads me to believe that all the tags have to be snake_case. I have not been able to find any documentation for each tag as the information is sparse and spread all over the internet. I have found what I believe is the source code: https://docs.ros.org/en/api/gazebo_plugins/html/gazebo__ros__imu__sensor_8cpp_source.html
And the tags are in CamelCase.
Does someone know what is going or, or can point me in the right direction?
